# in TYPO3, there seems to be something wrong with the charset of my dates

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, locale, typo3, fluid

in EXT:news, I am getting bad character sets for my spelled out dates . Why's that.

Here's the template

```
<time datetime="<n:format.date format="%Y-%m-%d">{newsItem.datetime}</n:format.date>">
        <n:format.date format="{f:translate(key:'dateFormat')}">{newsItem.datetime}</n:format.date>
</time>
```

And in TS:

```
plugin.tx_news._LOCAL_LANG.de {
    dateFormat = %d. %B %G
}
```

Result:
07. f�vrier 2014

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Steffen Müller's old post: 
http://www.t3node.com/blog/fixing-locale-problems-for-dates-in-typo3/

```
config {
    locale_all = fr_FR.utf-8
}
```

Solves it

Comment: Tried it, works as expected and solves all my problems with the dates. Thnx.